# Necessary to increase size?

Tags: system-installation

I used the Windows installer to install Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit. The PC also has Vista Ultimate 32 bit.

In any case, I recall that one of the question asked was where and how much space to provide for Ubuntu installation, which I think I allocated 10 GB on a pretty large partition.

Is there a way to allocate more than 10 GB now that Ubuntu is installed?  If so, how?  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use gparted software to resize another partition and add resized partition to your Ubuntu partition. Goto software center and type gparted. Most of the case the first result will be the GParted software(Free software) itself install and enjoy.

**Updated**: Both facts mentioned by Uri Herrera are true. But I've made some assumptions here. Continue if your system has partitions like this.
1. You have at-least 3 partitions, one for Windows, second for Ubuntu, another for your stuff.
If this is so, you can resize partitions other than Ubuntu and Windows partition using gparted but you cannot add to Ubuntu since it was mounted.

So you can do from windows itself. 
Browse and download Easeus partition manager. You can do both resizing and adding to Ubuntu partition. At-least you can expand up-to 30 GB.

Comment: *I used the Windows installer to install Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit..* - This means he used **Wubi**. Wubi can't use more than 30Gb. And most definitively can't be resized with Gparted. Moreover you can't resize a mounted partition.